# Nested classes - separating the declaration from the definition in C++

Tags: c++, nested-class

Is it possible to separate class declaration from its definition? Of course it is, but what if I want to have an object of this class before the actual definition of it? Consider the following example:

```
class ID3_Reader{
    public:
        // code omitted for brevity
    protected:
        class Mp3_File;
        Mp3_File mFile;                                             
};
```

It's obvious that it will not compile. I would have to define the Mp3_File class inside the ID3_Reader class. It's not a problem when I have just two classes. What if there would be like five of them? My code would become pretty messy. To avoid this problem I would have to separate the class declarations from their definitions. How can I achieve that? Remember that I need an instance of the Mp3_File class inside the ID3_Reader class.
The reason why I'm using nested classes is because I don't want some other programmer to use the Mp3_File class. I used "protected" keyword because I will create classes based on the ID3_Reader class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by using a pointer like the other guys answered:

```
class Mp3_File; // forward declaration of class Mp3_File

class ID3_Reader{
    public:
        // code omitted for brevity
    protected:
        Mp3_File *mFile;                                             
};
```

Or you can declare the constructor of `class Mp3_File` private and declare `class ID3_Reader` `friend` of `class Mp3_File`:

```
class Mp3_File {
  Mp3_File() {} // constructor is private
  friend class ID3_Reader;
};

class ID3_Reader{
    public:
        // code omitted for brevity
    protected:
        Mp3_File mFile;                                             
};

auto main() -> int {
    ID3_Reader r;
    Mp3_File m; // Error Mp3_File constructor is private!

  return 0;
}
```

Thus, other people won't be able to use `Mp3_File` while you can use it in the scope of `class ID3_Reader`.

Comment: I like the idea of class friendship. However every answer was helpful. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining `mFile` as an instance of `Mp3_File`, define it as a pointer to an `Mp3_File`. That way you won't need to know the definition in the header file. Or better yet - use a smart pointer. You will then need to create the real instance by using `new` in the class constructor and `delete` it in `ID3_Reader`'s destructor.

If you wish to stay with your current syntax to access `mFile` from outside of the class, dereference it inside the accessor function:

```
Mp3_File& getMp3(){ return *mFile; };
```

Then - if `Mp3_File` has an overloaded `operator()` (or any other overloaded operator as a matter of fact), you won't need to dereference it every time manually.

Answer (score 1):

It won't compile because the compiler doesn't know how much memory that Mp3_File class will use. If you change it to a pointer

```
class ID3_Reader{
    public:
        // code omitted for brevity
    protected:
        class Mp3_File;
        Mp3_File *mFile;                                             
};
```

that compiles just fine (a pointer has a fixed size -  http://ideone.com/VmmXfK).

I suggest using a pointer instead of a complete member variable and initialize/deinitialize it in the ctor/dtor.

I don't see another way of doing it without changing the "nested classes" design.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using pointers. Recall that although you must have a full class to define a variable, a simple forward declaration is good to define a pointer:

```
class ID3_Reader{
    public:
        // code omitted for brevity
    protected:
        class Mp3_File;
        Mp3_File *mFile;                                             
};
```

Unfortunately, this puts you on the hook for managing the memory for the nested class, but it does hide all of the internals of the class from outside programmers.

Comment: Well from my understanding I can use the std::unique_ptr right? If so  I won't have to worry about memory management.

Comment: @user3125731, Yes, if this thing is being `new`ed, then `std::unique_ptr` is a much better alternative. Do note that it will make the class non-copyable by default, though.

Comment: @user3125731 Correct, using a smart pointer would free you from the need to deallocate the pointer. The memory for the object would need to be allocated separately, though, which may not be ideal if you wanted a "stack object".

Answer (score 1):

You can make your class a class template to work around this restriction: for class templates the definition of the nested type needs to be visible at instantiation time, not while looking at the definition of the class template. You might want to use a `typedef` to actually name the used instantiation to avoid the need to have a trailing `<>`. Here is a quick demo:

```
 template <typename = void>
 class ID3_ReaderT {
     public:
         // code omitted for brevity
     protected:
         class Mp3_File;
         Mp3_File mFile;                                             
 };
 typedef ID3_Reader<> ID3_Reader;

 template <typename  T>
 class ID3_ReaderT<T>::Mp3_File {
 };

 int main()
 {
     ID3_Reader reader;
 }
```

Of course, it still means that every user of `ID3_Reader` needs to see the definition of the nested type. If you want to avoid that, your option is on level indirection, i.e., using a pointer as was already stated by multiple answers.